# Clear specific LocalStorage in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to clear a specific `localStorage` in `html` using `javascript`:

```
localStorage.setItem("one");
localStorage.setItem("two");
//How to clear only "one"
```

Comment: This isn't hard [to look up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#examples).

Comment: Please note that we expect you to [do some decent research before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). I find it hard to believe that by trying multiple search queries on Google, or simply looking at localStorage documentation, you wouldn't be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove an item from the `localStorage` with the [`removeItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) function:

```js
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

So in your case:

```js
localStorage.removeItem("one");
```

Comment: Sorry, ok, "the docs" was not correct. Thank you for removing or exchanging the link.